# Hidden Fields that Need to be Required When Visible

Tags: forms, xpath, orbeon, required

I am currently building a form in Orbeon Forms 4.6. I am having difficulty with making all of my hidden fields required when they show. Currently, I have the following XPath expression in my Visibility Formulas tab: $indicia='yes'. All this is doing is saying that if the user answers YES to the INDICIA question, show the remaining questions.

However, how can I get the remaining questions to be required ONLY if the user selects YES in the INDICIA question? I know that in 4.7 they have added a very user friendly way of going about this, but does anyone have any ideas on how else this can be done?

Thank you to anyone who can help,

EataSandwhich

Comment: What you are describing here should be the default behavior: you can mark a field as required, and it will only be "actually required" if the field is visible. Are you seing something different? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thank you avernet for your response. Unfortunately if the questions remain hidden and are set to required the user will not be able to submit their form. Any ideas on setting some conditional rules that relate to requirements with Orbeon? I am very new to all of this, but have a basic understanding. Is there any other language that can work with XPath in Orbeon to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a new form you're creating with Form Builder, with just 1 field, make it required and non-visible, and then checking you can't save the data? I don't remember this having changed since 4.6, but if you can reproduce the issue as described, can you also try to reproduce it with 2017.2, and see if you're having the same problem?

Comment: That did work! I know that I have tried it in the past without any success, but it finally worked! Maybe I did wrong last time, I don't know. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: OK, I'm glad it ended up working. And since this content won't be useful in the context of Stack Overflow (this is a question with no answer that can be given), I'd recommend you just delete your question.